# Real Analysis - Sequence Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having a hard time figuring out this proof.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an M such that $|x_n-x|\leq \epsilon$ for all $n\geq M$. Show that $\lim x_n=x$.

My attempt:
Let $\epsilon>0$. (Need to find M?) Let $n\geq M$...$|x_n-x|\leq \epsilon$

My scratchwork:

$\lim x_n=x$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim x_n-x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim (x_n-x)=0$ ???

It's because it's so close to the definition that I don't know what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What definition of convergence are you using? Certainly the usual one is exactly what you have down as the problem.

Comment: The definition we have is as follows: A sequence $\{x_n\}$ is said to converge to a number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x|\leq \epsilon$ for all $n\geq M$. So the difference is in my problem we are given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and must show the sequences converges to $x$. A tutor hinted that I must find a value for $M$ but I don't know how. All the other problems we've done we've been given a distinct sequence whereas this is generic. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @cantor'ssloth You should edit your question to include the **original definition** of $\lim x_n = x$. I doubt that it is that in your comment because it would be identical with the statement in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The definition for convergence that I will be using is as follows:
We say that the sequence $(x_n)$ *converges* to $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if, given any $\epsilon > 0, $ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N.$

---

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then, by definition of $(x_n)$, there exists $M$ such that
$$|x_n - x| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

By the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R},$ there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N_0 > M.$ We choose $N = N_0.$

So, for all $n\geq N,$ we have
$$|x_n - x| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$$
thus $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

---

Please see if this proof makes sense to you. I think the closeness to the original definition is intentional and it would be instructive for you to prove the converse to see that these are equivalent definitions.

Comment: This makes so much more sense now. I had a feeling Archimdean would show up somewhere but I couldn't put all the pieces together properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A more high-level view. Convergence and limit properties can be defined with “open” inequalities $…<\varepsilon$ or “closed” ones: $…\le\varepsilon$ in any metric space. The closed and open balls are both local bases for the topology, so it doesn’t matter which criterion you use.

Fix any $\varepsilon>0$ and any $0<\varepsilon’<\varepsilon$. Then $|x_n-x|\le\varepsilon’$ means $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$. The point is, when such inequalities can be satisfied for *any* $\varepsilon$, you can always pick $\varepsilon’$ smaller to fit your needs. The definitions are equivalent.

Comment: The definition in the OP's comment also uses "$\le$".

Comment: @PaulFrost That is strange then. The problem statement is identical to the definition! I had assumed they were quibbling between $\le,<$.